# nextjs - using meta refresh to reload page give me 404

Tags: next.js

I have created a codesandbox to show this problem:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/charming-surf-kmtbib

Essentially this is the index page:

***index.tsx***

```
import Head from "next/head";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Head>
      <meta httpEquiv="refresh" content="0; url=/login" />
    </Head>
  );
}
export default Home;
```

Note: I tried this aswell but also fails

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

const Home = () => redirect('/login/');
export default Home;
```

***pages/login/login.tsx***

```
import Head from "next/head";
import styles from "@/styles/Home.module.css";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Hello world</title>
      </Head>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Only going to /login returns 404

How to load this page in the dev mode of nextjs? Maybe there is something I can configure in next.config.js like webpack devserver historyApiFallback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh. I realised the path was wrong. it was /login/login